# Java execution in background

Tags: java, background, daemon

i have developed an app which executes sql jobs.
When I click on execute button the my application goes into running state and it halts untill the query is executed.

I want my app should not halt and the user should be able to enter other query and those query execution should run in background.

My question is how to run the execution of queries in background?
means when the execute button is clicked ,the remaining execution should run behind the screen.

My app is developed using struts1.3 framework.I have written the main functionality in execute() of Action Class

Code snippet of execute()

```
DAO dao1=new DAO();
                    System.out.println("Here...1");
                    con1=dao1.DBConnection(jndiname);
                    Statement st = con1.createStatement();
                    //status_id=1;
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query); 
                    System.out.println("Here...2");
                    String id = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    //int req_id = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    String dirTree= rsBundle.getString("CSV_DIR");
                    File f=new File(dirTree);
                    String[] directories = dirTree.split("/");
                    String[] lists=f.list();

                    for (String dir : directories )
                    {
                        if (!dir.isEmpty() )
                        {
                            if (f.exists())
                            {

                                System.out.println("directory exist");
                            }
                            if (!f.exists())
                            {
                                boolean success = (new File(dirTree).mkdirs());
                                if(success)
                                {
                                System.out.println("directory created");
                                }

                            }

                            }

                            }
                    for(String s:lists)
                    {
                        System.out.println("files.." + s);
                    }
                    String csv_file_path=dirTree+"/";
                    String csv_file_name=id +".csv";
                    //writing to csv file
                    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv_file_path + csv_file_name), ',',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

                    writer.writeAll(rs, true);
                    writer.close();
                    //status_id=7;
                    String zip_file_path=rsBundle.getString("zip_file_path");
                    String zip_filename=id + ".zip";

                    String zip_file_pwd=rsBundle.getString("zip_file_pwd");
                    //zip file creation
                    ZipUtil.zipDirWithPassword(dirTree,  zip_file_path + zip_filename,zip_file_pwd);
                    String ftp_file_path=rsBundle.getString("ftp_file_path");
                    long zip_file_size= new File(zip_file_path + zip_filename).length();
                    System.out.println("File size..inside" + zip_file_size);
                    System.out.println("Here...3");
                    String exec_id=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("userLoginId");
                    //int executor_id= Integer.parseInt(exec_id);
                       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
                       //get current date time with Date()
                       Date date = new Date();
                       System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

                    String query4 = "select executor_id,email_id from m_executor where windows_id = '" +  exec_id + "'";
                    System.out.println("Query... " + query4);
                    //int i=0;
                    iPreparedStatement4=con.prepareStatement(query4);

                    iResultSet3=iPreparedStatement4.executeQuery();
                    while(iResultSet3.next())
                    {
                        //restriction=iResultSet2.getString(1);
                        exec_email=iResultSet3.getString(2);
                        executor_id=iResultSet3.getInt(1);
                    }

                                    ValueListForExec db= new ValueListForExec();
                    String status_name="";
                    status_name=db.getStatusName(status_id);

                    if(zip_file_size <= 5242880){
                        System.out.println("send via email");
                    /*}
                    else
                    {*/
                        System.out.println("send via FTP");
                        upload.upload(host, usrname, pwd,zip_file_path + zip_filename, ftp_file_path,zip_filename);
                    }


                    String insertquery="{ call sp_process_job (?,?,?,?) }";

                    cs = con.prepareCall(insertquery.toString());
                    cs.setString(1,id);
                    cs.setString(2,host);
                    cs.setString(3,usrname);
                    cs.setString(4,pwd);


                    cs.execute();

                    con.commit();
```

Comment: You need to use Threads. I suggest using an ExecutorService because it makes it easier to manage the tasks.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: Try to research about [Thread](http://www.roseindia.net/java/thread/)

Comment: Java is a very large playground. Can you provide more context? Is this a Swing app? SWT? Eclipse RCP? There are different approaches depending on the UI framework you are using.

Comment: When the button is clicked, you need start a new thread to execute SQL job, and the button should be disabled until SQL job is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are about to enter the world of threading.

To run a task in the background you need to start that task on a separate thread. 
If you are running in a Swing app you will need to ensure that you are not running the task on the event-dispatcher thread.

Have a look at SwingUtilities invokeLater.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) or Java Threads to do this job . You can write you sql job in Runnable/Callable object and once user click the button job should be given to other thread which will execute in background.Even you can use Thread Pool to transfer jobs to pooled thread.